# Does ''direct sum '' in the definition of graded ring mean internal direct sum?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I just read the definition of graded ring on wiki. a graded ring is a ring that is a direct sum of abelian groups $R_{i}$such that $ R_{i}R_{j}\subseteq R_{i+j}$. Does it mean internal direct sum here?

Comment: Yes, in the usual definition of a graded ring.

Comment: @darijgrinberg thanks, and do we always mean internal direct sum when we say decomposition into direct sum?

Comment: Depends. Most of the time, yes.